# How can I abstract out this .each function?

Tags: javascript, each

I have a switch case statement in some javascript, which then needs to run the same `.each` function, with just a parameter change.

```
$('#item_type').change(function() {
        switch(this.value) {
            case 'CH':
                $('#item_code').empty();
                $.each(cheeses, function(key, value) {   
                     $('#item_code')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",key)
                    .text(value));
                }); 
                break;

            case 'Z':
                $('#item_code').empty();
                $.each(sizes, function(key, value) {   
                     $('#item_code')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",key)
                    .text(value));
                }); 
                break;
        }

    });
```

How can I change things so that the `.each` function is only defined once, and can just be called inside the various cases, something like this:

```
case 'CH':
    $('#item_code').empty();
    doEach(cheeses);
    break;
case 'Z':
    $('#item_code').empty();
    doEach(sizes);
    break;
```

Comment: `function doEach(collection) { $.each(collection, ... ); }`.

Comment: Thanks, that did what I needed. If you post as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straightforward approach would be:

```
function doEach(collection) {
    $.each(collection, function(key, value) {   
        $('#item_code')
            .append($("<option></option>")
            .attr("value",key)
            .text(value));
    });
}
```

or you could go with very simple plugin:

```
$.fn.populate = function (collection) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var $self = $(this).empty();
        $.each(collection, function (key, value) {
            $('<option>').attr('value', key).text(value).appendTo($self);
        });
    });
};

$('#item_type').change(function () {
    switch (this.value) {
        case 'CH':
            $('#item_code').populate(cheeses);
            break;

        case 'Z':
            $('#item_code').populate(sizes);
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can store the each function in a variable and then pass it to the .each like this:

```
var addOptions = function(key, value) {   
                 $('#item_code')
                .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value",key)
                .text(value));
            };

$('#item_type').change(function() {
    switch(this.value) {
        case 'CH':
            $('#item_code').empty();
            $.each(cheeses, addOptions); 
            break;

        case 'Z':
            $('#item_code').empty();
            $.each(sizes, addOptions); 
            break;
    }

});
```

Good luck!